# Attach array of mp3 to images updating to the DOM

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a function that generations random numbers and pushes to a array.

The array passes to the crystal reset function where it empties the DOM and generation new crystals with random numbers after every win or lose.  I have created a new array with songs that I want to attach to each images and play when they are clicked.

```
function crystalReset() {
  $("#crystals").empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < randomCystals.length; i++) {
    var imageCrystal = $("<img>");
    imageCrystal.addClass("crystal-image");
    imageCrystal.attr("src", images[i]);
    imageCrystal.attr("src", sounds[i]);
    imageCrystal.attr("data-crystalValue", randomCystals[i]);
    $("#crystals").append(imageCrystal);
  }
}
function runAgain() {
  $(".crystal-image").on("click", function() { 
    var crystalValue = ($(this).attr("data-crystalvalue"));
    crystalValue = parseInt(crystalValue);
    totalScore += crystalValue;
    $('#total_score').html("<b>Total Score:</b>  " + totalScore);
```

Comment: There is missing totalScore somewhere before - in `totalScore += crystalValue` you make a sum of nothing and `crystalValue`.

Comment: Your question seems incomplete. What exactly is the expected behaviour of the code you put up in the question and what are you observing ?